# How to filter only specific nested objects during serialization for REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Java and Spring Boot to create an REST API for a database.

I have been trying to find a way to dynamically filter serialized java nested objects. I have seen filter solutions with @JsonFilter but I can't manage to get it working with nested objects.

Here the object to be serialized:

```
package org.safetynet.p5safetynetalert.dbapi.model.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Collection;

@Data
public class ChildFromAddressDTO {
  private String title = "List of child at selected address";

  @JsonFilter("childrenAtAddressDynamicFilter")
  private Collection<PersonDTO> childrenAtAddress;

  @JsonFilter("otherAdultsAtAddressDynamicFilter")
  private Collection<PersonDTO> otherAdultsAtAddress;
}
```

As you can see, I have tried to filter the two different objects contained into `ChildFromAddressDTO`. Indeed, I want to filter their properties dynamically when `ChildFromAddressDTO` is being serialized.

To be more specific, here is the `PersonDTO` object:

```
package org.safetynet.p5safetynetalert.dbapi.model.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;
import lombok.Data;
import org.safetynet.p5safetynetalert.dbapi.service.AgeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Data
@JsonFilter("PersonDTODynamicFilter")
public class PersonDTO {

  @Autowired
  private AgeService ageService;

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String phone;
  private String birthDate;
  private Integer age;
  private String email;
  private AddressDTO address;

  public PersonDTO() {

  }
}
```

I would like to hide everything except `firstName`, `lastName`, and `age`, but only for the collection named `childrenAtAddress`.

So far, I have tried this code in the service linked to my controller service:

```
@Service
public class ChildAlertService {

  @Autowired
  private AddressService addressService;
  @Autowired
  private PersonService personService;

public MappingJacksonValue getChildrenFromAddress(String road) throws Exception {
    ChildFromAddressDTO childFromAddressDTO = new ChildFromAddressDTO();
    Collection<PersonDTO> childrenToAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    Collection<PersonDTO> adultToAdd = new ArrayList<>();

    Address address = addressService.getByRoad(road);
    Collection<PersonDTO> personDTOCollection = addressService.getPersonDTOsFromAddress(address);

    for (PersonDTO personDTO : personDTOCollection) {
      if (personDTO.getAge() < 19) {
        childrenToAdd.add(personDTO);
      } else {
        adultToAdd.add(personDTO);
      }
    }
}

    childFromAddressDTO.setChildrenAtAddress(childrenToAdd);
    childFromAddressDTO.setOtherAdultsAtAddress(adultToAdd);

    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter myFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter
      .serializeAllExcept("phone", "birthdate", "email", "address");

    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
      .addFilter("childrenAtAddressDynamicFilter", myFilter);

    MappingJacksonValue personsDTOtoChildren = new MappingJacksonValue(childFromAddressDTO);
    personsDTOtoChildren.setFilters(filters);


    return personsDTOtoChildren;
  }
```

Is there a way to do so using @JsonFilter dynamically?

Because with this code, I get an 500 internal server error and I cannot manage to understand why.